# Alternative to UNION clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two table :- table a, table b.

table a

---ID---

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 7
```

table b

---ID----

```
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

I have to get Output Like this without **UNION** Command:-

----ID-----

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

*Note: I have one solution with union:-*

```
  **select * from a
      UNION
   select * from b;**
```

*I need alternative to this. please experts suggest.*

Comment: Why can you not use the UNION statement?

Comment: I'm curious: why you cannot use `UNION`?

Comment: Mike, it's like a challenge given by someone who is good programmer so I am not using UNION otherwise i have solution with union as well as i post it too.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question?

Comment: Is the question about MySQL or SQL-Server? Or both?

Comment: Please suggest for MYSQL

Comment: It's for me is MYSQL..

Comment: I seriously doubt this can be done in MySQL without `UNION`.

Comment: @ypercube : You can do it !!!

Comment: No, I can't. It may be possible to prove it's impossible though.

Comment: @ypercube : Oh..We can't here this from you, ;)

Comment: Are you allowed to use other tables, besides these two?

Comment: Sure, Even you can use DUAL table. but I want only single query..

Comment: The mysql version is done, please check it in the edit :)

Comment: This is a valid question as UNION is not supported by hibernate HQL. It would really great if someone could give an answer which can be used at a production level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need another table with (at least) 2 rows for this:

```
CREATE TABLE d
  ( id INT NOT NULL 
  );

INSERT INTO d
  (id)
VALUES
  (0), (1) ;
```

Then, if we want to have only one query, we can use (**this is for fun, DO NOT USE in production**, that's why we have **`UNION`**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(aa.id, bb.id) AS id
FROM 
    d
  LEFT JOIN a AS aa ON d.id = 0
  LEFT JOIN b AS bb ON d.id = 1
WHERE 
    COALESCE(aa.id, bb.id) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    id ;
```

Tested at **[SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbee48/1)**, and for other table combinations:

[1 row - 1 row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e30f8/7)
[2 rows - 2 rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36bf7/2)
[0 rows - 1 row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a27fe/2)
[0 rows - 2 rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03d770/3)
[0 rows - 0 rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0e4bb/2)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

I think it works well in MS-SQL, change it to MySQL if you need, but MYSql doesnot support full outer join! Good luck

```
    SELECT (
      CASE
        WHEN b.ID IS NULL
        THEN a.ID
        WHEN b.ID=a.ID
        THEN b.ID
        ELSE b.ID
     END)
    FROM
      (SELECT ID FROM table2
      )b
    FULL OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT ID FROM table1
      ) a
   ON a.ID=b.ID
```

and play around with the query
Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c657d/13

And here is the MYSQL version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) id


 FROM 

(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME <> 'table_a' n
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
     AND TABLE_NAME IN('table_a', 'table_b')
) t LEFT JOIN table_a t1 
    ON t.n = 0 LEFT JOIN table_b t2
    ON t.n = 1
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c657d8/34

Comment: atleast drop in the reason for the minus!

Comment: I guess because this will return only the `id` from the `b` table.

Comment: How can he change it to MySQL if MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`, that is the problem...

Comment: yes thats why iv mentioned that full outer join is not supported in mysql, its actually a union of right outer join and left outer join, it just cancels the neg in a way ;)

Comment: Yeah, but the FULL joins are done with UNION usually in MySQL - which is excluded by the question requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are avoiding `UNION` but you can do like following

```
CREATE TABLE temp_ids(ID INT);

INSERT INTO temp_ids SELECT ID FROM a;
INSERT INTO temp_ids SELECT ID FROM b;

SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM temp_ids;
```

Comment: Abdul, it's not a single query. I want single query so i can't use this too.

Comment: @user3327460 You said ***"alternative to `UNION`"***, without any further restrictions. This qualifies as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try a full outer join and filter the `NULL` values.

Comment: Can you please explain with query ?

Comment: Yes. Explain query as well here .? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work on MYSQL, but something like `select id from a full outer join b on a.id = b.id where id != null`

Comment: MySQL has not implemented `FULL JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

As an abstract exercise (if this is an interview question we expect a kickback!) one ugly, innefficient solution would be to create a cartesian product and filter the unique values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(a<>b, b.id, a.id) 
FROM a, b
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Comment: What if there was 8 in b ?

Comment: @Abdul: that has no relevance to the outcome - try it.

Comment: I have already tried that 8 is not coming in output. have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c657d8/1

Comment: Ah yes - the 7 is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN t2.id 
         ELSE t1.id 
       END AS id 
FROM   t1 
       FULL OUTER JOIN t2 
                    ON t1.id = t2.id 
ORDER  BY id
```

Note: Mysql does not support full outer joins.

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7684/10

Comment: Please suggest for MYSQL