# remove the union in this query and still get the same result

Tags: mysql, rdbms

My query is

```
SELECT effective_to
     , department_flag
     , secondary1_changed_on
     , organization_active_flag
     , etl_run_number
     , row_current_key
  FROM db_name.d_internal_organization
 WHERE d_internal_organization.group_lvl_flag = 'Y' 
   AND d_internal_organization.current_flag = 'Y'    
  UNION
    Select '2999-12-31 00:00:00','N',NULL,'Y',9999999,9999;
```

I want the same result having removed the union 
as our platform doesn't support it

Comment: I would change platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to UNION clause in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877357/alternative-to-union-clause-in-mysql)